# .net framework TimeZoneInfo.utc property

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i found these definition in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.utc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

for TimeZoneInfo.Local:

> A TimeZoneInfo object that represents the local time zone.
>   The local time zone is the time zone on the computer where the code is executing.

yeah, it`s pretty clearly that i can understand, but for TimeZoneInfo.Utc:

> A TimeZoneInfo object that represents the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) zone.

what`s the utc zone? does this mean "the utc zone is the time zone on the computer where the code is executing but with utc format" ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is the primary time standard by which the world regulates clocks and time. It is one of several closely related successors to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). For most purposes, UTC is synonymous with GMT, but GMT is no longer precisely defined by the scientific community.

Good enough? :)

Comment: Yep, only **GMT is no longer precisely defined by the scientific community.** :) ... communities ... go figure ...